# Hot Chocolate top-level properties from multiple sources

Tags: graphql, .net-6.0, hotchocolate

I have an entity (Customer) that needs to pull data from multiple sources. The schema looks roughly like this:

```
{
   id: string
   name: string
   address: string
   contact: string
   status: string
}
```

The `id`, `name` and `address` come from an EF datacontext. The `contact` and `status` fields come from a *single* REST endpoint, and looks like this:

```
GET /url/customer?id=1234
{
  id: '1234'
  contact: 'joe@bloggington.com'
  status: 'ACTIVE'
}
```

If I put both `contact` and `status` into a single field/object (i.e. `ContactStatus`), then it would be a simple case of creating an extension for `Customer`. But these fields are not related, and should be regarded as different *top-level* fields.

Is there a way to ensure that the REST endpoint is called only once, when fetching all values? Essentially resolving both fields when fetching one or the other maybe?

`Hot Chocolate v12.15.0`, `net6.0`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the batching api to do this

Create a DataLoader that loads the data from the rest endpoint. This way you can also optimize the fetches from the rest endpoint (if the endpoint supports somthing like  /url/customer?ids=1234,2345,5930)

e.g. `class YourDataloader extends BatchDataLoader<int, AdditionalCustomerData>`

Then you can just do

```cs
[ExtendObjectType<Customer>]
public class CustomerExtensions 
{

   public Task<string> GetContactAsync(
      [Parent]Customer customer, 
      YourDataloader dataloader) 
   {
     var result = await dataloader.LoadAsync(customer.Id);
     return result.Contact;
   }

    public Task<Status> GetStatusAsync(
      [Parent]Customer customer, 
      YourDataloader dataloader) 
   {
     var result = await dataloader.LoadAsync(customer.Id);
     return result.Status;
   }
}
```